# How to avoid of file name validation in SaveFileDialog C#

Tags: c#, wpf, file, validation, savefiledialog

Is it possible to avoid of fileName validation in SaveFileDialog?

```
  var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog {
Filter = "Job package (*.job)|*.job", 
CheckPathExists = false,
 ValidateNames = false };

 var result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result.Value)
        {

           ....my own validation....
        }
```

The ValidateNames property doesn't work. Anyway, when I type a name with invalid characters, the dialog shows it's own popup "The file name is not valid".
Can I avoid it? How?

Comment: By _invalid characters_ do yo mean character that cannot be used in path or for example path that does not exits?

Comment: I mean characters that can't be used in filenames. E.g. ':' or '|'

Comment: But what's the point of having path with invalid characters that you cannot create? Why do you need it?

Comment: I want to handle it myself and use my standart warning message.

Comment: I need this for path templating purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenFileDialog does not allow '/' character even after disabling validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007494/openfiledialog-does-not-allow-character-even-after-disabling-validation)

Answer (score 0):

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Job package|*.job";
            saveFileDialog.CheckPathExists = false;
            saveFileDialog.ValidateNames = false;
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName,"");
            }
```

Wow that was asked 6 years ago LOL

Comment: Hi Leo, Doesn't this do the opposite of what the OP wants, when `saveFileDialog.ValidateNames` is set to `true`?

Comment: Yeah I fotrgot to change the booleans to false haha. I edited it though.