# OpenFileDialog does not allow '/' character even after disabling validation

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Similar question: [How to avoid of file name validation in SaveFileDialog C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667972/how-to-avoid-of-file-name-validation-in-savefiledialog-c-sharp)

I am writing an application that has an option to support opening executables and running them with given parameters, and I am trying to use `OpenFileDialog` as a user-friendly way to achieve this. After disabling `AddExtension`, `ValidateNames`, `CheckFileExists` and `CheckPathExists`, I can pass parameters to executables and the application runs them using the arguments as intended.

However, when I attempt to pass parameters that include "invalid" filename characters (such as '/'), I am stopped and get this example message:

[image: Example validation message]

and am not allowed to continue, even though `ValidateNames` is set to false.

Here is the code concerning the dialog:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.AddExtension = false;
dialog.CheckFileExists = false;
dialog.CheckPathExists = false;
dialog.ValidateNames = false;
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    //Parse text manually here (parsing is fully handled on the developer side)
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this and completely disable input validation, or do I have to write a custom file dialog implementation?

Comment: Unanswered duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667972/how-to-avoid-of-file-name-validation-in-savefiledialog-c-sharp

Comment: Oh, do I have to close my question down?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to abuse and not use the OpenFileDialog, it's mean to well, open files, not launch programs and take parameters, why not let it do just that and then popup a second control with a string input for the parameters?

Comment: No, just mentioning it so that it shows up in the "Linked" section for future visitors to find.

Comment: In that case I would re-implement the dialog in order to make usage more streamlined.

Comment: I see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn457282.aspx) that the `FOS_NOVALIDATE` flag says "Do not check for situations that would prevent an application from opening the selected file, such as sharing violations or access denied errors." -- which has nothing to do with illegal characters. I suspect you are out of luck here, and might have to write your own dialog - or just use a separate one for parameters as suggested above.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads up anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override the default validation. As such you will either have to ask for the parameters in a separate dialogue or re-implement the file open dialogue yourself.